# How to redirect to correct state in ui-router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, state

When a I enter the url "/samsung" I don know what state should be use so it will just match on the first one in this case category.

I have done some reading and I thing I should use the UrlMatcher and then based on that redirect to the proper state... but how?

https://ui-router.github.io/docs/latest/classes/url.urlmatcher.html

I have 4 states.

```
 const home = {
    name: 'home',
    url: '/',
    component: 'home'
 };

 const category = {
    name: 'home.category',
    url: '{categoryName}',
    component: 'category'
 };

 const product = {
    name: 'home.category.product',
    url: '{productName}',
    component: 'product'
 };

 const cmsPage = {
    name: 'home.cmsPage',
    url: '{pageTitle}',
    component: 'cmsPage'
 };
```

I have a service that can provide me with a page type based on the url.

so using the service with the parameter "samsung" will give the response of "category" and "galaxy" will give "product" etc...

Answer (score 0):

Except home. All others routing URL is defined as `url:'variable-name'`. But, it should be `url: '/route-name/variable-name'`. Something like,

```
 const category = {
        name: 'home.category',
        url: '/category/:{categoryName}',
        component: 'category'
     };
```